# Merge the "career" and "career-development" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are questions tagged [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career), and questions tagged [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development). The two tags should probably be merged, as questions about career development are still questions about career.